# Why is it that if $|G|=p^{n}$ then $|Z(G)|\neq p^{n-1}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am reading a proof about why If $|G|=p^{n}$ (where $p$ is prime) then $|Z(G)|\neq p^{n-1}$?

That proof says that if $|Z(G)| = p^{n-1}$ then $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic which makes $G$ abelian.

My question is: So what if $G$ is abelian? because in the questions it doesn't say that $G$ is not abelian.

Is a group of order $p^{n}$ can't be abelian?

Comment: $G$ is abelian if and only if $G = Z(G)$.

Comment: To answer your last question. There are certainly abelian groups of order $p^n$. For example, the cyclic group $\mathbb Z / p^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $G$ is abelian then $G=Z(G)$ .What will be the quotient group then?Does it contradict what is given to you?

Comment: What's the point of looking at the (trivial) quotient? If $G = Z(G)$, we already have a contradiction.

Comment: Yes that is what i meant that you get a contradiction

Comment: I don't see how the contradiction has anything to do with the quotient.

Comment: The contradiction lies in the fact that on the one side you get the order of the quotient group as $p$ and then by using the fact that the group is abelian you get the order to be 1.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. But it's still an unnecessary step. If $G = Z(G)$, then $|G| = |Z(G)| = p^n$, hence $|Z(G)| \neq p^{n-1}$.